# Content in ::after not moving after being positioned abaolutely

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to add an open and close triangle to my dropdown menu using CSS ::after concept.  [Here's my code](https://jsfiddle.net/pritam1605/9apc5dkz/2/).

```
<div class="row-links-platforms-and-flavor">
  <div class="website-links">
    <ul class="outer-links">
      <li><a>Other Links</a>
        <div class="links">
          <ul class="inner-links">
            <li><a class="website-link" href="#"
                target="_blank">Link 11</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="website-link" href="#"
                target="_blank">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="website-link" href="#"
                target="_blank">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

$color-white: #fff;
$color-black: #000;
$color-grey-light: #eaeaea;
$color-grey-dark: #F2F2F2;
$color-services-light: #951D21;
$color-services-dark: #7d1119;
$color-benchmarks-light: #44546a;
$color-benchmarks-dark: #303c4a;
$color-disabled: #e8e8e8bf;

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}


.website-links {
      flex: 1 1 15%;

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;

      .outer-links {
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;

        &:hover .inner-links {
          transform: scale(1, 1);
          transition: all 150ms ease-in;
        }

        &::before {
          content: '\25BC';
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          color: $color-services-light;
          left: .5rem;
        }

        &:hover::before {
          content: '\25B2';
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          color: $color-services-light;
          left: .5rem;
        }
      }

      // 2022
      .inner-links {
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: .5rem;
        background-color: $color-grey-light;
        z-index: 1000;
        width: 20rem;
        top: 100%;
        right: -50%;

        box-shadow: 0 0 1.5rem rgba($color-black, .15);

        transform: scale(1, 0);
        transform-origin: top;
        transition: all 150ms ease-in 200ms;

        li {
          font-weight: 400;
          text-align: center;

          &:not(:last-child) {
            border-bottom: 1px solid $color-white;
          }

          &:hover {
            background-color: $color-white;
            font-weight: 700;
          }

          a {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 1.5rem;
            color: $color-black;
          }
        }

      }
    }
```

The triangle doesn't move to the right. If I don't give any position, the triangle appears properly at the beginning, but, I want it at the end of Other Links. What am I missing?

Comment: You're applying both `right: 0` *and* `left: .5rem`. The `left` declaration is overriding the `right` declaration. If you want the arrow to appear on the right side of the text, consider using a negative `right` amount **or** a `left` amount greater than 100%.

Comment: @TylerRoper thank you pointing out my mistake :)

Comment: @TylerRoper the left property isn't overriding the right property it's merely steretching the element from `0.5rem` from the left edge to `0` from the right. if you'd a background you'll be able to see it

Comment: @ZohirSalak You're correct, "override" was not the appropriate term. Perhaps "conflicting" or "interfering" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face it is , that first you set left: .5rem and after that you set right:0;

If you want to get it to the right , remove left property and add right: -.5rem or wahtever you want it :)

```
&::before {
          content: '\25BC';
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: -1rem;
          color: $color-services-light;
          /* remove it left: .5rem; */
        }
```

Hope this explanation could helps you ...

I forgot to add and this change on hover :

```
&:hover::before {
          content: '\25B2';
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          right: -1rem;
          color: $color-services-light;
          /* left: .5rem; */
        }
```

I think, `right:-1rem;` is what we looking for

Comment: I'd say `left: 100%;` to be consistent